# R - How to set text language when exporting plots with devEMF

Tags: r, plot

I work with R-Studio in kubuntu 16.04. My language settings are:

```
> Sys.getlocale()

[1] "LC_CTYPE=de_AT.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=de_AT.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=de_AT.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"

> Sys.getenv()

...

LANG               de_AT.UTF-8

LANGUAGE           de_AT:de

...
```

However, if I export a plot with the "Enhanced Metafile Graphics Device" ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devEMF/)), for instance:

```
emf("file.emf"); hist(somedata, main = "Überschrift"); dev.off()
```

and then import file.emf into MS Word (on another PC) and make it editable, all the text of the plot is in US English.

**Question 1**:  Is it possible to obtain plots with text languages other than English?

**Question 2**: How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I realize my answer is late, but adding information for posterity)

There are two graphics formats supported by devEMF:

- **EMF**. Locale / language information is not included in the EMF format specification except to distinguish languages with vertical vs. horizontal text.
- **EMF+**. Locale / language information IS included in the EMF+ specification, but this feature is not implemented by devEMF.

That said, Unicode characters are fully supported for both formats and should not disappear or otherwise change when viewed/edited in MS Word.